# Selenium webdriver explicit wait for alert throws UnhandledAlertException

Tags: java, selenium, exception, alert

I have to wait explicitly for 20 seconds for presence of an alert. If alert is not present after 20 seconds, I should throw an exception. Following is my wait for alert, but it throws unhandled Alert Exception before 20 seconds. Can someone help me on this?

```
try {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class)
            .ignoring(UnhandledAlertException.class) 
            .until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your wait is throwing the `UnhandledAlertException`? Or is it some line after this block that is throwing the error.

Comment: This wait itself is throwing the error.

Comment: Your catch block is catching the timeout exception the wait would throw if it doesn't find the alert. Why not just get rid of the try catch? Or if you want to throw a custom exception, catch the `WebDriverTimeoutException` and throw your custom error. I'm not sure why you're getting an `UnhandledAlert` error, but you can always catch that within your `until()` block as well if you need to. I know debuggers sometimes stop on those even if it works fine when running normally

Answer (score 2):

How about writing your own `ExpectedConditions` class?

```
public abstract class MyExpectedConditions {
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForAlert() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                driver.switchTo().alert();
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                return true;
            } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

}

Usage:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(MyExpectedConditions.waitForAlert());
```

Explanation:
WebDriverWait causes switch to alert during 20 seconds. If alert is NOT present, `Exception` is thrown an caught. If `driver` successfully switches to `alert`, it returns to `defaultContent` and continues with your code.

If you want to handle this alert, you will have to switch to alert by yourself.

Comment: Thank you that helped in my situation.