# How to show the alert in 10 seconds in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

**My Requirement:**
I want to show the alert on my page some seconds to read.If any function is to help in Selenium Web-driver.

I am a new bee to this automation fields I have studied about the explicit wait so I use the explicit wait as below but It doesn't show the alert in my required time.

Below is my code,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username"))).clear();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username"))).sendKeys(username);          
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password"))).clear();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password"))).sendKeys(password);      
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Login"))).click();   
String det1 = driver.findElement(By.id(elem id)).getText();
String det2 = driver.findElement(By.id(elem id)).getText();
String det3 = driver.findElement(By.id(elem id)).getText();
String det4 = driver.findElement(By.id(elem id)).getText();    
js.executeScript("window.alert('Values are..'"+det1+" "+det2+" "+det3+" "+det4"+'')");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

the above code is good to show my det values but **it shows the alert in very little time and closes the alert.** So How I make the alert to show my details in some seconds before it's closed.

Comment: Use Thread.sleep(10000) before accepting the alert.

Comment: @Pradeephebbar thanks for the quick reply. Can I use the Thread and explicit in same time?. I hope explicit time is used instant of use thread.

Comment: This might help for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373356/selenium-webdriver-explicit-wait-for-alert-throws-unhandledalertexception/42395106

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use an alert to display information. Use a framework like TestNG or JUnit to log pass/fails and then look at the logs. You want automation to go as fast as it can. It defeats a lot of the purpose of automation when you require manual intervention or someone watching the script run to see if it passed or not.

Comment: thanks to the answer for giving the new info about alert in automation :).

Comment: Yes. very loooong period. I am actually following the rule as you described in your answer. I do not use an alert to show some information for some time. this question in my starting period doubt. So thanks again for the info again. Your word is the answer for my question.